# gem install mysql2 windows native extention etc problems

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems

I have perused many sites and nothing that has worked for everyone else seems to be working for me.

```
 C:/Users/Holly/Desktop/Brolie>gem install mysql2 Temporarily enhancing
 PATH to include DevKit... Building native extensions.  This could take
 a while... ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
         ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes checking for
 rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
 checking for rb_intern3()... yes
 *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
 the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
 options.

 Provided configuration options:
         --with-opt-dir
         --without-opt-dir
         --with-opt-include
         --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
         --with-opt-lib
         --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
         --with-make-prog
           --without-make-prog
         --srcdir=.
         --curdir
         --ruby=C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
         --with-mysql-dir
         --without-mysql-dir
         --with-mysql-include
         --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
         --with-mysql-lib
         --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/ extconf.rb:37:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError )


 Gem files will remain installed in
 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql 2-0.3.13 for inspection.
 Results logged to
 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/ext/mysq
 l2/gem_make.out
```

My DevKit is the correct download. I've tried adding the connector, that didn't do anything. Doing a step by step installation through a class and so I know I'm doing things in the correct order but nothing is helping this error.

Answer (score 0):

That actually seems like a bug on `extconf.rb:37` instead of a missing dependency or some compilation problem.

Assuming that you triple-check that your ruby version is supported by this version of the gem and you are using the lastest version supported for your ruby version, I suggest [open an issue on github](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2).

Comment: Thank you! I had tried getting the mysql gem instead of mysql2 and had the same issue. Heading to github now. Much appreciated.